# How to loop through pandas dataframe, check conditions, perform string manipulations & write to a new column?

Tags: python, string, pandas, loops, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe like below;

```
--------------------------------
Col1    Col2                    
--------------------------------
1       AppVer: 1.1.1 | name: A 
0       name:B                  
1       AppVer: 2.3.1 | name: B
```

I wanted to create a new column (newCol3) based on the condition
1. If Col1=1 then split the Col2 based on "|" and write to the column newCol3
2. If Col1=0 then write "Not Applicable" to the column newCol3

I tried the below code for loop using iterrows & conditional statements;

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row['Col1']==1:
        df1['newCol3']="NA"
    elif row['Col1']==0:
        a=row['Col2'].split("|")
        df1['newCol3']=a[0]
```

But i the value in newCol3 is not as expected as shown below.
Also, i get a warning like this
*"**main**:8: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy"*

**Obtained Output:**

```
---------------------------------------------------
Col1    Col2                        newCol3
---------------------------------------------------
1       AppVer: 1.1.1 | name: A     1.1.1
0       name:B                      1.1.1
1       AppVer: 2.3.1 | name: B     2.3.1
```

**Expected Output:**

```
---------------------------------------------------
Col1    Col2                        newCol3
---------------------------------------------------
1       AppVer: 1.1.1 | name: A     1.1.1
0       name:B                      Not Applicable
1       AppVer: 2.3.1 | name: B     2.3.1
```

Provide me any help/suggestions.

Comment: Why does it look like your if statement is backwards?  Shouldn't you want to split the value if the Col1 == 1

Comment: should it be np.where ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I would suggest using `loc` to create a new column.

Docs: [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Docs: [str expand](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

Docs for str extract: [str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

```
df.loc[df['Col1']==1,'Col3'] = df['Col2'].str.extract(pat='insert the pattern here')
df.loc[df['Col1']==0,'Col3'] = 'Not Applicable'
```

Just saw the expected output. Read the docs I linked and change the `str.extract` as required.

Comment: Thanks Sid. But sorry I didnt understand the extract part. so i've modified your code with split now & it worked. df.loc[df['Col1']==1,'Col3'] = df['Col2'].str.split('|').str.get(0)
df.loc[df['Col1']==0,'Col3'] = 'Not Applicable'

Comment: @Simbu see the answer above mine. Regex patterns are a great way to go about extracting exactly what is required from a string.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you can do

```
df['New']=df.Col2.str.extract('(\d*\.?\d+\.?\d+)').fillna('Not Applicable')
df
Out[43]: 
   Col1                      Col2             New
0     1  AppVer: 1.1.1 | name: A            1.1.1
1     0  name:B                    Not Applicable
2     1  AppVer: 2.3.1 | name: B            2.3.1
```